# use Spring @scheduled in server

Tags: spring, client-server, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I'm using @scheduled to schedule a task in server using

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
```

but task is not called since the client trigger every second other function in the server.
How can I force the server to trigger also the scheduled task (the order doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you forgot to use `@EnableScheduling` annotation in your configuration.

Comment: No, I have it under @SpringBootApplication,
the task is scheduled only when the ui not trigger the server